# Store UTF8 character into MySql using php

Tags: mysqli, utf-8

I am facing little issue about utf8 character.i know a lot of answer exist but my problem not solved.
i have a string when i echo then in browser it works fine but when i store into database then it show like

```
Pø¦.OÝ.XØ±1⸮24ø¿ø… (browser) > PÃ¸Â¦.OÃ.XÃ˜Â±1â¸®24Ã¸Â¿Ã¸â€¦ (Database)

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
   die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
$db->set_charset("utf8");
```

How can i save utf8 character to database.I already tried

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

i don't understand what's the problem.is there any font issue?

Comment: How exactly are you checking the contents of the database?

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score -1):

your problem is your database ,change your database collation to general_ci like this

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

maybe  its worth to read this [PHP, MySQL, characters not being displayed correctly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883694/php-mysql-characters-not-being-displayed-correctly?rq=1)

Comment: i think you didn't change your database collation

Comment: An incorrect column collation would lead to discarded characters, not random transformation.

Comment: @Haseeb have you tried inserting data using a normal insert query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @jameshwart yes i inserted data and it insert successfully in phpmyadmin

Comment: @Haseeb is the inserted data is discarded characters?

Comment: @jameshwartlopez i insert (Pø¦.OÝ.XØ±1⸮24ø¿ø…) and it insert same as i input no any change after saving in phpmyadmin.but when i insert through php then it creates a problem i also tried with simple query using insert into  in phpmyadmin and it added successfully as i expected

Comment: maybe you should try altering your database collation to utf8_general_ci and tell me what happen after you did it :)

Comment: sorry sir. i thought your problem is your database